# Hover a div while pointing on the labal

Tags: html, css, button, hover

I have a button with hover CSS and I'm having trouble to setup the hover rules for the entire structure.

[This is the button without hover:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PIHu.png)

[This is the button when I'm pointing on the div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiBRm.png)

[This is the button when I'm standing on the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwwID.png)

HTML:

```
<div class="cta-button accessibility" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="open new_tab"><div><span class="cta-button-background " style="background-color: rgb(255, 108, 0); border-color: rgb(255, 108, 0);"></span><label>Learn more</label></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
 .live-board .cta-button .cta-button-background {
  background-color: #FF6C00 !important;
    border-radius: 33px !important;
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
     border: 2px solid #FF6C00 !important;
  
  }

  .live-board .banner-box .banner-container .banner-content .cta-button.accessibility :hover label{
  background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
  color: #FF6C00 !important;
  
  }

  .cta-button.accessibility .cta-button-background:hover {
    background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
  color: #FF6C00 !important;
  }

  .live-board .banner-box .banner-container .banner-content .cta-button.accessibility label:hover + .cta-button-background  {
  background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
  color: #FF6C00 !important;
  
  }
```

How can I make the hover be applied when I'm standing with the mouse on the div?

Answer (score 0):

> Your second css section, just check, there is a space between ... **.accessibility :hover** label{...
> The space between is a CSS selector for descendants.
> if you want the label only to be called with hover consider decoupling the classes and selecting them in CSS , example--> Label:hover attribute triggers

```
    label:hover {
   color:yellow;
}
``
```